# How to force snowflake views to inherit the table comments and the column comments?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Recently started using snowflake and have the task of ensuring that tables and the views on top of these tables have comments on them and the columns.

Is there an option in snowflake to import the comments of the underlying table and columns into the view so that I don't have to manually create the same comments on the view and the view columns again?

If not any better workaround?

These are just direct views using `select * from the table` (Reason because we expose only views to external users and not tables)

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does allow you to add optional column comments in the column alias clause of the CREATE [OR REPLACE] VIEW statement, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW db.schema.view_name (
  col1 COMMENT 'this is col1',
  ...
  colx COMMENT 'this is colx'
)
AS
SELECT col1, ..., colx FROM ...;
```

See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html

After the view is created, you can only change the view comment via the COMMENT and ALTER VIEW statements, but not the column comments, unless you re-create the view.

Comment: Be aware that the COMMENT is not after the SELECT, but before in parenthesis...

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, you can add comments to views and tables.  In addition, you can add comments for each column in a table.  Unfortunately, you cannot add comments to view columns.

However, if you wanted to apply the comments of the tables to similarly named views (there would have to be some naming standard that allows you to derive the view name from the table name), you can do this programmatically.

In a stored procedure, use the query below to get all the table comments.  Then loop through each row and dynamically build and execute the ALTER TABLE  SET COMMENT = .

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG , TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COMMENT
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA."TABLES"  
WHERE
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
```

The table column comments can also be retrieved from the information schema, but you won't be able to add that to the view metadata.

```
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.COMMENT
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA."TABLES"  t
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA."COLUMNS" c
        ON t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG 
        AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
        AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE
    t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Hope this helps.